# Горизонтальные поля в адаптивном меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Необходимо ссылкам в адаптивном меню добавить внутренние отступы. Какие единицы измерения выбрать: **rem/em** или **%**? 
Как **правильно** поступить в дальнейшем с меню при уменьшении размеров экрана:

1. Уменьшить размер текста и, соответственно, отступов, а при невозможности уменьшения, изменить положение пунктов меню (н-р: с горизонтального на вертикальное)?
2. Задать отступы в %, а при невозможности их дальнейшего уменьшения  изменить положение пунктов меню?

Comment: единицы измерения ловя чего какие выбрать? горизонтальные поля - это типа `border` имеете ввиду? было бы хорошо увидеть хотя бы изображение с меню

Comment: Имеется ввиду padding. Сейчас нет возможности добавит пример. Речь идёт о меню состоящем из 6-и пунктов расположенных в один ряд.

Comment: Мне также не до конца понятен вопрос, нарисуйте схему-макет(пусть и самую простую), что там за горизонтальные поля, для `пунктов расположенных в один ряд`. `Как правильно поступить в дальнейшем с меню при уменьшении размеров экрана:` Рассмотрите вариант полностью его скрыть(в мобильной версии), и добавить кнопку, при нажатии на которую, меню будет появляться( базовый пример http://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/vywEbJ )

Comment: @A.Gr padding это внутренний отступ, а не горизонтальные поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rem - работают относительно корневого элемента (html)
em - относительно текущего контекста

Если вы не уменьшаете базовый размер шрифта на мобильных устройствах, то нет смысла использовать rem. Он как раз и нужен для управления размером относительно корневого элемента.

1. Лучше так, чем второй вариант. Медиа запросы для чего.